# How to compare classes within two differents RDF

Tags: python, linux, rdf, rdfs

For a project in school i have to compare two ontologies whose are in RDF formats.
I can code in python but i'm not against any kind of language.

My main question is : Is it possible to compare classes of different RDF files?

Comment: loading both datasets doesn't work? And "compare" means what?

Comment: I want to know wich classes are common or differents from one to an other

Comment: Please explain **in your question** what "RDF" is, maybe add a link to a reference. Show some example input and the expected output. Please [edit] your question to add more information instead of writing comments. Assume that most users here don't have knowledge about your specific problem or use case, so you should explain your problem detailed enough for someone who is new to your field of interest.

Comment: @Kair0 and how do you define "difference"? Anyways, as I said , you can always load both dataset into the same graph. You can use `rdflib` in Python

Comment: @Bodo not sure what you're saying. RDF is a standard W3C language for data. The question is even tagged with `rdf` - what should he explain here and why?

Comment: Answer to your main question is "Yes." I'm sure that's not very helpful. More details about what you're working with, and what your goals are, would help others provide helpful answers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some helpful hints.

Answer (score 0):

Pedantic note on "RDF format", RDF has a number of representations 
including ntriples, quads, turtle, rdfxml, notation3 but the
representation does not matter as they all represent a graph which is 
none of them.

Short answer to the question is something like
 yes! of course you can ... you will just probably be wrong.

But that is a little misleading, for the formal answer search on "graph isomorphism".

For a useful way to start thinking about it consider the
difference between two prose documents, which is easy, 
because each is an ordered list of items (words). 
Even when they are not identical you can say which parts 
are the same, and which parts are close or really divergent.

When the documents are ontologies they are not an ordered list of items, 
they are unordered lists of unordered lists of items where the items are allowed different names/representations in each document.

So we punt on the fact it is (nigh) impossible as the ontologies grow larger and find heuristics that allow us to say something useful in the meanwhile. 
"Semantic Similarity" the art of judging if two graph fragments
represent the same concept (are these classes the same?).
It can use whatever you can afford to bring to bear on the problem.